# Deep nested Array of Objects, find and remove Object with specific ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I am trying to find an Object by ID and remove it. (Of course if this object has subTasks all Objects hanging on this tree are removed too).
I have a structure like this (For example), which can grow very big and deep:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "lane": 0,
    "name": "Task A",
    "start": 0,
    "end": 10000,
    "subTasks": [
      {
        "id": "0.1",
        "lane": 0,
        "name": "Subtask",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 10000,
        "class": "danger",
        "sublane": 0,
        "subTasks": [
          {
            "id": "0.1.1",
            "name": "Subtask",
            "start": 0,
            "end": 10000,
            "subTasks": [
              {
                "id": "0.1.1.1",
                "name": "Subtask",
                "start": 0,
                "end": 10000,
                "subTasks": [
                  {
                    "id": "0.1.1.1.1",
                    "name": "Subtask",
                    "start": 0,
                    "end": 10000
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "0.1.1.1.2",
                    "name": "Subtask",
                    "start": 0,
                    "end": 10000
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "0.1.1.2",
                "name": "Subtask",
                "start": 0,
                "end": 10000
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "0.1.2",
            "name": "Subtask",
            "start": 0,
            "end": 10000
          },
          {
            "id": "0.1.3",
            "name": "Subtask",
            "start": 0,
            "end": 10000
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "0.2",
        "name": "Subtask",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 10000
      }
    ],
    "class": "danger",
    "sublane": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "lane": 2,
    "name": "Task B",
    "start": 15000,
    "end": 25000,
    ],
    "class": "success",
    "sublane": 0
  }
]
```

Now I want to remove the ID = 0.1.1.1.1 for example, but it should work with every other Object the same way, no matter how deep it is nested.

For finding and editing Im using this dfs algorithm:

```
   edit: function (name, start, end) {
        for (let obj of gantt.items()) {
            result = dfs(obj, id);
            if (result) {
                result.name = name;
                result.start = start;
                result.end = end;
            }
        }
    
      dfs: function (obj, targetId) {
            if (obj.id === targetId) {
                return obj;
            }
            if (obj.subTasks) {
                for (let item of obj.subTasks) {
                    let check = dfs(item, targetId);
                    if (check) {
                        return check;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        },
```

But how can I remove/delete the specific Object?

Comment: You can set the parent array of the element you want to remove to a new array without this value. For this, you could use the `Array.filter(...)` method.

Comment: It is a recursive find

Answer (score 3):

Kind of recursive filter:

```js
const data = [{"id":"0","lane":0,"name":"Task A","start":0,"end":10000,"Subtask":[{"id":"0.1","lane":0,"name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000,"class":"danger","sublane":0,"Subtask":[{"id":"0.1.1","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000,"Subtask":[{"id":"0.1.1.1","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000,"Subtask":[{"id":"0.1.1.1.1","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000},{"id":"0.1.1.1.2","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000}]},{"id":"0.1.1.2","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000}]},{"id":"0.1.2","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000},{"id":"0.1.3","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000}]},{"id":"0.2","name":"Subtask","start":0,"end":10000}],"class":"danger","sublane":0},{"id":"1","lane":2,"name":"Task B","start":15000,"end":25000,"class":"success","sublane":0}];


const removeById = (arr, targetId) => arr.reduce((acc, obj) => 
  (obj.id === targetId) 
    ? acc 
    : [ ...acc, 
        {
          ...obj, 
          ...(obj.Subtask && { Subtask: removeById(obj.Subtask, targetId) }) 
        }
      ]
, []);

console.log(removeById(data, "0.1"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```